# jQuery to replace image paths across the page based on browser viewport

Tags: jquery, string, image, path, replace

I am trying to load a dynamic sidebar based on the browser view-port. How can I replace a particular word of image path with jQuery variable?

**My code:**

```
body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="aside"> </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
        <p><img src="img/bar-0/sample.jpg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet justo vel diam interdum posuere. <img src="img/bar-0/sample1.jpg">Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla sed libero nunc. Cras in lacus in dolor feugiat scelerisque nec id nisi.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet justo vel diam interdum posuere. Aliquam erat volutpat. <img src="img/bar-0/sample2.jpg">Nulla sed libero nunc. Cras in lacus in dolor feugiat scelerisque nec id nisi.<img src="img/bar-0/sample2.jpg"></p>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var curwidth, script, prevclass;

function reloadBars(width) {    var newclass
        width = parseInt(width, 10);
    newclass = ""
    if (width < 801 && (curwidth == -1 || curwidth > 800)) {
        newclass = 'bar-0';
        bar = '800.php';
    } else if ((width > 800 && width < 1201) && (curwidth < 800 || curwidth > 1201)) {
        newclass = 'bar-1';
        bar = '1000.php';
    } else if ((width > 1200 && width < 1601) && (curwidth < 1200 || curwidth > 1601)) {
        newclass = 'bar-2';
        bar = '1200.php';
   } else if (width > 1600 && curwidth < 1600) {
        newclass = 'bar-3';
        bar = '1600.php';
   } else {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: bar,
        data: {},
        success: 
        function(response) {
            $('#aside').html(response);

            $('#aside').addClass(newclass);
            $("#aside").removeClass(prevclass);

        $("img").each(function() {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            src = src.replace(prevclass, newclass);
            $(this).attr('src', src);
        });

        prevclass = newclass;


        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("UH OH! Error!");
        }
    });
    curwidth = width;
}
prevclass = ""
curwidth = -1;
reloadBars($(this).width());

    $(window).resize(function() {
       reloadBars($(this).width());
    });
});

</script>
</body>
```

Here in particular I want to replace `bar-0` wherever it appears in `<img>`, with the variable`newclass` value. I am trying to achieve that by using this code as shown above:

**UPDATE :** It gives an error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/final/bar-1img/bar-0/sample1.jpg"
```

Ideally the path should be `http://localhost/final/img/bar-1/sample1.jpg` It should replace `bar-0` but it is appending before the `img/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete answer to this depends on the starting text. But you will most definitely want to employ the prevclass and newclass again.

```
//do this after the $.ajax portion of the reloadBars() function. Remove the previous call of prevclass = newclass and place it after the following code.

$("img").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src')
    src = src.replace(prevclass, newclass)
    $(this).attr('src', src)
})

prevclass = newclass
```

Comment: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/final/bar-1img/bar-0/sample.jpg" sample.jpg` Ideally the path should be `http://localhost/final/img/bar-1/sample.jpg` It should replace `bar-0` but it is appending before the `img/`.

Comment: Are you testing this anywhere live?

Comment: All you needed to do was set `prevclass="bar-0"` at the beginning, since that is what you put in the html markup as the default starting image. If you change the starting image, you'll have to change this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to replace is the 'src' attribute, not the content.
Try with this:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    src = src.replace("bar-0", newclass);
    $(this).attr('src', src);
});
```